# determine approximate time complexity of a program using statistical methods

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, time-complexity, curve-fitting

Here are the output values for bubbleSort :

```
n = [10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000, 100000]
```

```
t = [9.368115451001358, 37.69119230900105, 85.12908719999905, 152.00092839799981, 242.2243322070026, 353.44638952199966, 487.97764714200093, 669.483528703, 873.3610439340009, 1091.256361742002]
```

I want to test for all common complexities like N powers, Logarithmic etc.
I tried fitting it to polynomial curve and test it using kolmogorov-smirnov test but did not receive accurate answers. Which is probably the fault of my curve fitting (numpy.polyfit).

---

I don't require code (it's okay if you can provide it) but want to dive into the concept and find the accurate way to approach the problem?

---

Edit : ran test with more inputs but the outcome is still indecisive and exact same as the previous result

Comment: Sounds more like a math question to me. https://mathoverflow.net/

Answer (score 1):

Your timings are too low to expect a good approximation. Everything below a few seconds is most likely result of a constant overhead plus a bit a noise and a very little part of the real computation time.

I would go for

`n= 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 (, 10000000)`

The largest n you choose should lead to at least a few minutes of runtime (if not take even a greater n)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24718926)

Comment: @Aksen P: 'timings are too low' are in my opinion an answer to why the approach seams to work. I think with better data the approach may work.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I ran the test from 10k through 100k but received same results from KS_2Sample Test. I think my approach is wrong, there has to be some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the data through my open source Python web site's "function finder" at zunzun.com, which uses the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to provide initial parameter estimates for fitting of non-linear equations. I set the function finder to look for equations with four or less parameters. Of the just over 340 equations that were tested, the best seems to be a Pareto type equation "y = 1.0 - (1.0 / pow(1.0 + a * x, b)) + Offset" with parameters a = -1.9034226324834123E-03, b = -1.1000895110345629E-02, and Offset = -1.1123894127275866E-03 yielding RMSE = 0.0005793 and R-squared = 0.9961

[image: plot]

Comment: I get similar answers for KS test for n^2, n^3 and so on. I should be able to distinguish between them. I can clearly see the difference with n and t but the P values are nearly identical.